# check if the link contains a string and add the rel='sponsored' attribute to it

Tags: jquery

i have to add attribute rel="sponsored" to all link in page that contain dnlink string.
I used the follow code but it doesn't work ...

```
$("a").each(function() {
   link = $(this).attr("href")
   if(link.indexOf("dnlink") > -1) {
        $(this).attr("rel","sponsored");
   } 
 });
```

where is the issue?

Comment: *when* do you run your code?  Make sure it's either at the end (just before `</body>`) or wrap it inside doc.ready `$(() => { ..yourcode.. })`

Comment: Your code, *as provided* and with extrapolated html, works fine, as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/3frg5dtn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared `link` correctly.

Your code before I've submitted this answer:

```
link = $(this).attr("href")
```

Should be:

```
const link = $(this).attr("href");
```

Look at this:

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  const link = $(this).attr("href");
  if (link.includes("dnlink")) {
    $(this).attr("rel", "sponsored");
    $("div").html(link);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/dnlink">dnlink</a>
<a href="https://example.com/not">not dnlink</a>

<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ops ...it's true ...thanks :)